# Using a function that'll allow me to bold specific cells in my data if it meets the requirements

Tags: javascript, if-statement, user-interface, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am currently trying to figure out how to make 4 numbers bold that is within a graph that has been provided to me. I need to make the two closest numbers to 5 (5.05 and 4.96) bold but they need to both be next to each other, so I believe I need to create a UI code to search along each row for this point, as soon as it passes 5.05 and hits 4.96, both of these values need to become bold.

Then I would need to create another bit of coding to then find the highest value and lowest value on the same row as the two previous values of 5.05 and 4.96.

In my coding below, this is my horrendous attempt of trying to start this but it obviously isn't working, plus it wouldn't allow me to use setBold() which is annoying. If anyone can help me, that would be amazing. I have left a link to my spreadsheet below so if you need a better idea of what I am trying to achieve, you can see it. If you do open it, it'll give you a message to activate the script, if you click no then you can still activate it by clicking on apply script in the menu bar. https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/15MeTJLX2hmyJb6qN-9TJn7_2ik9mKZ8bCnv0CEyXiYI/edit?usp=sharing

```js
function searchOutput() {

  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  var dataSet = sheet.getRange("C3:W13").getValues();
  
  if (dataSet > 5){ sheet.getActiveCell().setFontColor("red").activate();}

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `setFontWeight("bold")`. `setBold` is a method for `Text class` which is under `DocumentApp`

#### Sample:

```
function setBold() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var data = sheet.getRange("C3:W13").getValues();
  data.forEach(function (row, i){
    row.forEach(function (cell, j){
      if(cell >= 5 && row[j + 1] < 5){
        sheet.getRange(i + 3, j + 3, 1, 2).setFontWeight("bold");
        sheet.getRange(i + 3, j + 3, 1, 2).setBackground("red");
      }
    });
  });
}
```

#### Output:

[image: output]

#### Note

- Condition is if current cell is greater or equal to 5 and right adjacent cell is less than 5, make it bold and have red background. (Remove red background line if not needed, added it for clarity only)
- Code above can set multiple pairs to bold if there are multiple pairs that satisfy the condition (It doesn't end after 1 pair). Although you can make it stop after first pair is found by adding another condition for it to end faster.

#### Resources:

- [setBold](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/text#setboldbold)
- [setFontWeight](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setfontweightfontweight)

Comment: Thank you for this, this will definitely solve my bold problem, but how would I set up a function so that my script will search through my data and make two numbers bold which follows a rule of that the first value is bigger or equal to 5 and the next value is less than 5?

Comment: I have edited my answer, please see the updated answer above. @KyeWilson

Comment: Hi @KyeWilson, If we answered your question, please click the accept button.  By doing so, other people in the community, who may have the same concern as you, will know that theirs can be resolved.  If the accept button is unavailable to you, feel free to tell me. stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer

Comment: I am finding another issue, it is making all the values 5 and above in column W bold. I think this is because it is counting all the values in column V as 0, so it is applying the rule to those values as well, I have been messing about with the coding to only collect the values that is in ("C3:W13") or ( 3, 3, 11, 21). Do you know why these aren't working?

Comment: Hi @KyeWilson, that shouldn't be the case, the condition is `cell >= 5 && row[j + 1] < 5`, so it shouldn't . But if there has a value in `X` which is less than 5 and `W` is >= 5, then it will set it to bold. I have modified the answer by specifying the range to use `C3:W13` Please recheck.

Comment: Yeah, I did try this, however, it no longer bolds the correct value? It is highlighting values 6.5 and 6.55, which is confusing me? So when I have it set on .getDataRange() bolds the correct values but it also bolds the extra values in column W. But when I use .getRange("C3:W13") it no longer bolds the values in column W which is good but it bolds the incorrect values?

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't able to actually offset the value. since `getDataRange` does always start from `A1` and now it was shifted to `C3`, I need to offset it now with `3` instead of `1` to set the correct cell into bold. I have updated the answer @KyeWilson, please verify if it now sets the correct cell into bold.

Comment: YESSS!!! That has worked perfectly, thank you so much for taking the time to helping me and other who will use this as well!

Comment: No problem @KyeWilson, glad to be of help. Good luck.